# Duplicate insert with Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have a code/condition to getting chat between users like:

```
    $chat = $chatRepository->findChat($firstUser, $secondUser);
    if (!$chat) {
        $chat = new Chat();
        $chat->setSecondUser($secondUser);
        $chat->setFirstUser($firstUser);
        $entityManager->persist($chat);
        $entityManager->flush();
    } else {
        ...
    }

    return $chat;
```

So if chat entity between users does not exist I create it. Problem is that somehow from frontend arrived two requests of getting this chat with half of second difference and in database I got two same records:

```
  id first_user  second_user    time
   1       1           2      10:20:20
   2       1           2      10:20:21
```

Which is wrong. How can I solve it without unique indexes? Thank you

UPD: findChat function

```
public function findChat($userId, $otherUserId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $qb->where($qb->expr()->orX(
        $qb->expr()->andX(
            $qb->expr()->eq('u.firstUser', ':firstUser'),
            $qb->expr()->eq('u.secondUser', ':secondUser')
        ),
        $qb->expr()->andX(
            $qb->expr()->eq('u.firstUser', ':secondUser'),
            $qb->expr()->eq('u.secondUser', ':firstUser')
        )
    ));

    $qb->setParameter('firstUser', $userId);
    $qb->setParameter('secondUser', $otherUserId);
    $qb->orderBy('u.dateCreated', 'DESC');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

Comment: Why not define it as a many-to-many relationship instead? That way you can have as many users as you'd like without having to add columns

Comment: What's wrong using an unique index on both foreign keys ? You can then get rid of the `id` if you are using a composite key from both FK

Comment: Many to Many is not ok for me because I simplified this table, its more complex really (more fields). But Doctrine does not support ManyToMany with extra fields.

Comment: Is `findChat` actually working? You could also [`LOCK`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html) the table.

Comment: Added this function to question, I saw this doctrine page, but really I dont see how I can apply this to my situation, can you point me may be?

Comment: @Serghei did you check out my solution below?

Comment: Thanks, but I need without indexes

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique key to your database which will prevent from adding same records. It can be done with `UniqueConstraint` annotation in your `Chat` entity.

---

**Example**

It may look in your `Chat` entity as follows:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\UniqueConstraint;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="chat", // your table name
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *         @UniqueConstraint(name="chat_unique", columns={"firstUser", "secondUser"})
 *     }
 * )
 */
class Chat
```

---

**More informations**

[Doctrine - UniqueConstraint Annotation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint)